# How inserting button from event in cell (react-data-grid)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

is there a way to insert the button(eg. button edit and delete) into the cell and click to get the whole row?
I tried, but such is not working:

```
{
    key: 'dontReading',
    name: ' ',
    width : 100,
    resizable: true,
    formatter : <span className = "btn-group  btn-group-sm"> <button type = "button" className="btn btn-primary custom-button-crud" onClick = {this.handleDontReading.bind(this) } > Edit page </button></span>
}
```

[image: MY TABLE]